# Folding back after unfolding

Tags: coq

I have `fold_length` defined like this:

```
Inductive list (X: Type) : Type :=
  | nil : list X
  | cons : X -> list X -> list X.

Arguments nil {X}.
Arguments cons {X} _ _.

Notation "x :: y" := (cons x y)
                     (at level 60, right associativity).
Notation "[ ]" := nil.

Fixpoint fold {X Y:Type} (f: X -> Y -> Y) (l:list X) (b:Y) : Y :=
  match l with
  | nil => b
  | h :: t => f h (fold f t b)
  end.

Definition fold_length {X : Type} (l : list X) : nat :=
  fold (fun _ n => S n) l 0.
```

I have to prove a theorem and this is my code so far:

```
Theorem fold_length_correct : forall X (l : list X),
  fold_length l = length l.
Proof.
  intros X l.
  induction l as [| n l' IHl'].
  - simpl.
    unfold fold_length.
    simpl.
    reflexivity.
  - simpl.
    unfold fold_length.
    simpl.
```

Right now, my goal looks like this:

```
  X : Type
  n : X
  l' : list X
  IHl' : fold_length l' = length l'
  ============================
   S (fold (fun (_ : X) (n0 : nat) => S n0) l' 0) = S (length l')
```

Now I want to convert the expression `(fold (fun (_ : X) (n0 : nat) => S n0) l' 0)` to `fold_length l'` using the definition of `fold_length`. Is there a way to do that in Coq (There seems to something named `fold` tactic in Coq. Can that achieve this.) ?

Also, is there a way to prove the above theorem without the usage of `unfold` and `fold` tactic ?

Comment: You can either rewrite to the right `now rewrite <- IHl'` or use an aux lemma: `Lemma fold_lengthE {X : Type} (l : list X) :
    fold_right (fun _ n => S n) 0 l = fold_length l.
Proof. now trivial. Qed.
` then rewrite using it.

Comment: @ejgallego Thanks. So something like `fold` cannot be used here ?

Comment: What is `fold`? AFAICT it's not in the [stdlib](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Lists.List.html). Please provide a self-contained example (with the right imports & definitions).

Comment: @Sibi as answered below, `fold` is usually not powerful enough to work well in most cases, YMMV, but usually one want to prevent unfolding itself instead of refolding. Controlling reduction is a bit complex in Coq, you can use `simpl` flags (see the manual) or deploy some other custom solution like mathcomp's `nosimpl`.

Comment: @ gallais Thanks, I have made it self-contained now. @ejgallego Thanks for the valuable input.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To answer your first question, yes, the `fold` tactic can be used here to replace the left side of the equality with `S (fold_length l')`. Usually, for a function `f`, `fold f` is not powerful enough to detect what it can fold. But if you specify the whole term, like here `fold (fold_length l')`, it works.

Regarding your second question, note that tactics like `reflexivity` or `assumption` can conclude if the terms involved are equal up to some simplifications. Here, the base case of the induction can be just `reflexivity`. For the second case, assuming that `fold` is `List.fold_right`, `simpl` can surprisingly simplify without unfolding and you should not need `unfold` or `fold` here either.